# String.format does not deliver the correct format for sizes larger than one hour

Tags: java, string, string.format

I would like to convert 3600000 milliseconds to the 01:00:00 format (means 01 hours: 00 minutes: 00 seconds). Unfortunately it gives me 2: 120: 00. At 60,000 milliseconds, he gives me 00:10:00, which is the correct result. Until 00:59:00 he outputs the numbers formatted, but everything larger than an hour no longer outputs it in the correct format

```
public static String formattedTime(long time) {
    int hours = (int) (time / 1000) / 60 / 60;
    int minutes = (int) (time / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (time / 1000) % 60;
    return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);

}
```

Comment: Note that the problem is about arithmetic. It has nothing to do with String.format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(formattedTime(3600000));
        System.out.println(formattedTime(4580000));
    }

    public static String formattedTime(long time) {
        // Convert time in milliseconds to seconds
        int milliToSec = (int) (time / 1000);

        // Get hours from total seconds
        int hours = milliToSec / 3600;

        // Get minutes from total seconds
        int minutes = (milliToSec / 60) % 60;

        // Get remaining seconds from total seconds
        int seconds = milliToSec % 60;

        // Return formatted string
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
01:00:00
01:16:20
```